# Span contents in angular get disappeared

Tags: angular

I am working with an Angular Project. Earlier `<span>` elements worked successfully. But Now contents of `<Span>` elements are not visible.

For an example, suppose that I have below span element in a component,
`<span>My Name is ABC</span>`. After I run the project and inspect the element, I can see below content.

```
<span _ngcontent-serverapp-c143="">&nbsp;</span>
```

Can you please let me know the reason for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you rendering these spans in your angular html code?

Comment: 1) npm run build:ssr
2) npm start

Comment: how does the html look like, not how you start/ build the app...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted out this issue. I had a component in my project like this

```
import { Component, HostBinding, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'span',
  templateUrl: './abs.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class abs implements OnInit {
  @Input() @HostBinding('class') absMainClass:string="";
  @Input() @HostBinding('innerHTML') absMainValue:string="&nbsp;";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

some how, above component having selector as "span" will effect to whole project. I am not sure the reason for it. After I change the selector into [span], the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

the _ngcontent- attribute to each element to provide component-specific CSS encapsulation, which is called View Encapsulation. This attribute is used by Angular to isolate the component's styles from the rest of the application, so that they don't interfere with each other.

To fix this issue, you need to make sure that the content of the  element is included in the component's template. You can try adding the content directly in the component's template, like this:

```
<div><span>My name is ABC</span></div>
```

Comment: Yes, span in the component's template.